# Joomla - delay on publishing new things

Tags: caching, joomla

If I disable the cache on Joomla 1.5 and I publish a new menu item or any other information on the site the new element don't appear immediately after.

If I enable the cache on Joomla 1.5 and I set it to 1 minute delay, and I publish a new menu item, I wait a minute, I do refresh, and I see no menu item.

I only see those new elements, after a certain period of time, regardless joomla configuration options on cache page.

What could this be?

Thanks a lot,
MEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that may have this same issue:

It seems that this is something related with Joomla 1.5.x only. Not sure on what configurations. The only way that we found to solve it was to:

If we go to Extensions (or addons not sure since this one is not in English).
Then we click under "plugin management" and then, we need to find the system-cache option, and disabled it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a broswer issue. I use firefox and used to have a delay in publishing so i got an addon that clears cache with one click.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1801/ < that is the link to the one i use. I dont get any issues with delayed publishing.
They are other addons that clear cache and also cookie sessions. 
Web developer toolkit is also worthy of a download to help you look at tags, image alts, etc.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue was happening on both IE and FF. :)